# When creating a nav in SilverStripe, what is the number after $Menu?

Tags: navigation, silverstripe, template-variables

The below template code from one of the tutorials on the official SilverStripe website (["How to create a navigation menu"](http://docs.silverstripe.com/en/3.2/developer_guides/templates/how_tos/navigation_menu/)) includes the template variable $Menu(1)

What does the (1) mean? What happens if it gets changed to something else?

```
<ul>
    <% loop $Menu(1) %>
        <li>
            <a href="$Link" title="Go to the $Title page" class="$LinkingMode">
                $MenuTitle
            </a>
...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs

> <% loop $Menu(1) %> Begins a loop through all the menu items,
>   repeating all the HTML that is in the loop for each one. By passing
>   (1) as an argument, we are asking the CMS to give us all the pages at
>   level 1 of the hierarchy. Changing that to (2) would give us all the
>   pages at the second level of the hierarchy in the current section, and
>   so on.

That's taken from the [video tutorials](http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/adding-dynamic-content) they have up now